# How to add text in input form with v-model data bindings

Tags: html, vue.js, data-binding

I can get salary data from my database using vue js like this

[image: salary without curency]

but I want to add curency code like this but I don't know how to do it

[image: salary with curency]

here is my code for my retrieve, the field key salary is a double
how to add " Rp. " in a input with vue js ??

```
  <div class="form-row">

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">

         <label class="col-form-label">Salary</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="nasabah.form.salary">

      </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `value` attribute instead of `v-model`. Then, I would advice you to make the input field `readonly` to prevent any unexpected behaviour that will arise when someone changes the value.

```js
data() {
  return {
    nasabah: {
      form: {
        salary: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <input
     :value="formattedSalaryWithCurrency">  //use the value attribute
     readonly // make it readonly to prevent unexpected behaviour
   >
</div>
</div>
```

```js
computed: { // a computed property will only re-compute when a dependency changes (in this case, this.nasabah.form.salary;)
  formattedSalaryWithCurrency() {
    return this.formatSalaryWithCurrency(this.nasabah.form.salary);
  }
}
```

```js
methods: {
  formatSalaryWithCurrency(amount) {
    `Rp.${amount}`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) of Vue for that.